# How to arrange 2 simple array data

Tags: php, arrays

I have array data attached in below image and i want to show it exactly like

[image: screenshot]

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [title] => VALID Act Introduction Advances Diagnostics Regulatory Reform
        [link] => https://www.advamed.org/newsroom/press-releases/valid-act-introduction-advances-diagnostics-regulatory-reform
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => MedTech Fighting Coronavirus on Multiple Fronts
        [category] => https://www.advamed.org/newsroom/press-releases/medtech-fighting-coronavirus-multiple-fronts
    )

[2] => Array
    (
    [title] => EPA Ethylene Oxide Value at Odds with Public Health, Best Science
    [link] => abc
    )
)
```

Comment: So - have you tried anything?

Comment: yes i tried but not be able to get my desired results.

Comment: Show the attempt

Comment: can you please help me to find solution?

Comment: Ican, show what you already tried.

Comment: You can do this easily with `array_map()`. Write a function that takes two strings and creates the associative array with `name` and `category` keys. Then call `array_map()` with that function and the two arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so finally below is my solution. we just need to sort it out with array map function.

$results = array_map(null , $title, $url);

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your first data stored in `$Title` array and second one stored in `$Link` array. Now populate those in `$Data` array.

```
$Data = [];
foreach($Title as $key=>$value){
      $Data[] = [
                  'title'=>$value,
                  'link'=>$Link[$key]
                ];
}
```

in `$Data` you'll get your desired output.

Comment: this could be a solution but not best approach.